# Spring Cloud: Git with JDBC backend

Tags: git, spring-cloud, spring-jdbc

**Problem:** I only have either JDBC **OR** Git working. Just one thing. If I change the property `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap` to `true` or `false`.

**Question:** How do I configure my application to work with JDBC **AND** Git?

I am attaching the contents of the *bootstrap.properties*.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: jdbc, git
  application:
    name: configuration-server
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      name: configuration-server
      server:
        jdbc:
          order: 1
        git:
          uri: <hidden>
          order: 2
    bus:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** It turned out quite by accident to find out that with such a bundle, you need to use the parameters for JDBC: APPLICATION, PROFILE and LABEL, the same by which you can find the configuration in the GIT repository. At the same time, in the opposite direction - it works differently. That is, to get the configuration from the GIT repository, you do not need to create the necessary entries in the database. And that's all, despite the fact that the priority for JDBC is higher than that of GIT.